# how to pass object that is passed from html element to a function in parent controller to a controller that is inside the parent controller

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I am trying to pass address object that is passed from html element to a function in parent controller(myAppController) to a controller(i.e. DialogController)  inside the parent controller. I am creating a md-dialog box, when edit button is clicked elements in the address object should show up in the md-dialog box. The md-dialog box is working but can't display the items in address.
This is my controller

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('myAppController', myAppController);
myAppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state','AddressesService'];
function myAppController ($scope, $state, AddressesService) {
var vm = this;
vm.addresses = AddressesService.query();
// this is a long controller so i cut short it to important part
$scope.showAdvanced = function(address, ev) {
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: DialogController(address),
    templateUrl: '/modules/carts/client/views/edit.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
  });
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, address) {
console.log("address"+" "+address); // says undefined
    $scope.hide = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    };
$scope.cancel = function() {
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
    $scope.answer = function(answer) {
      $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
  }
 };
}
}());`
```

and this is my html

```
<div ng-repeat="address in vm.addresses">
<h5 class="list-group-item-heading uppercase bold" ng-bind="address.name"</h5>
<button ng-click="showAdvanced(address, $event)">Edit</button>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to pass data to a dialog controller is to use the parameter 'locals'

try this :

```
$mdDialog.show({
controller: 'DialogController',
templateUrl: '/modules/carts/client/views/edit.tmpl.html',
parent: angular.element(document.body),
targetEvent: ev,
clickOutsideToClose:true,
fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
locals: {
  address: address
  }
});
```

Note that your controller name should be between quotes : ''